# Cargo NoClassDefFoundError when having a webapp which uses jetty modules embedded 9.1.1

Tags: java, maven, jetty, cargo

I am using cargo maven plugin for testing purposes. Cargo is used to start our webapp and then REST API tests are run against it.
We are using jetty 9.1.1.

I am using cargo version: 1.4.8

Here is the configuration of the cargo plugin:

```xml
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-core-uberjar</artifactId>
                <version>${cargo.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${cargo.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <wait>false</wait>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>jetty9x</containerId>
                            <timeout>180000</timeout>
                            <artifactInstaller>
                                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jetty-distribution</artifactId>
                                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                            </artifactInstaller>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>standalone</type>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.servlet.port>${jetty.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                                <cargo.jvmargs>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</cargo.jvmargs>
                                <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>simple-war</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                                <location>${unpacked.war.directory}</location>
                                <properties>
                                    <context>portal</context>
                                </properties>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>                              
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-server</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-server</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>                                          
                </plugin>                
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Our code in one of the servlets uses `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context`

Since we are running in production with jetty embedded, we configure in the module which uses this in `pom.xml` with the `provided` scope for jetty modules.

There are no problems in production.

But when running in cargo, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler$Context
at my.package.DefaultServletConfiguration.setServletConfig(DefaultServletConfiguration.java:42)
at my.package.InitServlet.init(InitServlet.java:204)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:612)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:395)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:461)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:321)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:817)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:510)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:441)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
... 45 more
```

I also tried to specify the scope as `compile` for the jetty modules in order them to be in the `lib` directory inside the webapp, but then seems like there are different class loaders problem. The loader which loads the `Context` class in webapp is different by the one which jetty is loaded.

What is wrong here?

### UPDATE

Same occurs with cargo version 1.4.14 and jetty 9.2.9.v20150224

---

### UPDATE 2

I have tried to put the *jetty-servlet* in classpath as additional jar dependency as per documentation of cargo maven plugin: [here](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide.html)

```
<container>
    <containerId>jetty9x</containerId>
    <timeout>180000</timeout>
    <artifactInstaller>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-distribution</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </artifactInstaller>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            ...
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</container>
```

Now I see there is a property on the `dependency` element, which is called `classpath`, which has 2 values: `shared` or `extra`. Default value is `extra`. I will try `shared` one, and will check the result.

### UPDATE 3

The `classpath` on `container` dependency with value `shared` didn't help.
I see that only the following jar visible from within my WebApp (from a servlet):

```
.../target/cargo/installs/jetty-distribution-9.2.9.v20150224/jetty-distribution-9.2.9.v20150224/start.jar
```

Comment: can you please post full stack trace

Comment: This kind of error also occurs when the static initialization fails (runtime exception in static block). But seems there are no static blocks in considered classes...

Comment: added the full exception. It also occurs with cargo version 1.4.14 an jetty 9.2.9

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `provided` from the dependency in question?

Comment: Didn't try it yet. I followed the documentation of cargo maven plugin how to add additional jars into classpath of the application (configured it as dependency in the 'configuration' section of the 'container' - I see that the jar jetty-servlet is brought to the container. But when I enumerate the classpath from within my web application (for debugging) I see that only the 'jetty-start' jar is in there. It is somehow does not appear in the classpath of the webapp.

Comment: Another thing is, that the same configuration with Jetty 7.5.4.v20111024 works fine.

Comment: In my case, WAR file contains same jar that provided by jetty lib/ext. ClassNotFoundException error caused via spring. After removed the jar from WAR, works fine.

Comment: I don't have the jetty jar inside WAR in the first place. And if I put there the same jar, then ClassCastException occurs. Clearly something is wrong with class loaders here.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I lost the battle with cargo, and ended with writing a simple extension on the jetty-maven-plugin to run assembled war in forked mode (in another JVM). I did it, because the original jetty-maven-plugin supplies forked mode only in mode of assembling it from various web-app modules. That's why I wanted to use cargo in the first place.